# Regex split a string using newline (unless it is between double quotes)

Tags: c#, regex, split, newline, double-quotes

I'm doing some delimited file handling.  The first thing I need to do is get all "lines".  After getting each line, I can split based on the specified delimiter. So, to get the lines I need to split a string using the various line designations (\r\n, \r, \n).  The following was working until I encountered a newline within a double-quote:

```
return content.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

So if you consider the following text (my original text escaped double quotes within double quotes with \" instead of ""), where each line is delimited by one of the line designations, and each field/column in the line is delimited by the pipe "|" character:

```
string s = "row1 col1|\"row1 \"\"col2a\"\"\r\nrow1 col2b\"|row1 col3\nrow2 col1|\"row2 \"\"col2a\"\"\rrow2 \"\"col2b\"\"\"|row2 col3\r\nrow3 col1|\"row3 col2a\nrow3 col2b\"|row3 col3";
```

Which equals the following string:

row1 col1|"row1 ""col2a""{CRLF}row1 ""col2b"""|row1 col3{CRLF}row2 col1|"row2 ""col2a""{CRLF}row2 ""col2b"""|row2 col3{CRLF}row3 col1|"row3 col2a{CRLF}row3 col2b"|row3 col3

Splitting the above with my original method results in 5 lines:

```
string[] result = s.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

But I would like splitting the above using a line delimiter (\r\n, \r, \n) to result in 3 lines:

```
result[0] == "row1 col1|\"row1 \"\"col2a\"\"\r\nrow1 col2b\"|row1 col3"
result[1] == "row2 col1|\"row2 \"\"col2a\"\"\rrow2 \"\"col2b\"\"\"|row2 col3"
result[2] == "row3 col1|\"row3 col2a\nrow3 col2b\"|row3 col3"
```

Has anyone had some luck coming up with a regex to split on lines (except within quotes)?

**Here is what I ended up with, thanks to Alan:**

```
public string[] GetLines (string fileContent) {
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([^""\r\n]*(?:(?:""[^""]*"")*[^""\r\n]*))", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    MatchCollection matchCollection = regex.Matches(fileContent);
    string[] result = new string[matchCollection.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < matchCollection.Count; i++) {
        Match match = matchCollection[i];
        result[i] = match.Value;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Are you trying to parse CSV?

Comment: The file could be separated by any delimiter.  Comma is one option.  In my specific case, it is a pipe separated file.

Comment: Sounds good. Please check my solution below. It's flexible and you can use any field delimiter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `Matches()` instead of `Split()`:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?m)^[^""\r\n]*(?:(?:""[^""]*"")+[^""\r\n]*)*");
MatchCollection m = r.Matches(s);
```

The inner part, `(?:(?:"[^"]*")+`, matches a double-quoted string that may contain escaped quotes.  The whole regex matches a line that may contain one or more double-quoted strings.  Note that the inner character classes (`[^"]`) can match `\r` and `\n`, where the outer ones (`[^"\r\n]`) explicitly exclude them.  The line-start anchor (`^` in multiline mode) prevents spurious empty matches between real matches.

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN2hW9/2). (It's in PCRE, but I've tested it in .NET, too.)

Comment: I'm liking this - Thanks!  This worked with my original question, but I've since realized that I was escaping my double-quotes within double-quotes incorrectly.  I should use "" to represent an escaped double-quote, but I was using \".  I tried your regex with my original string (using \") and it worked!  But, it does not seem to work with the correct escaped double-quote "".

Comment: @Michael: That makes the regex much simpler.  See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, Alan.  I guess your new solution MUST be used in multiline mode?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, otherwise you'll only ever get one match.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following regex:

```
var fieldSeparator = "|";
var strRx = $@"""[^""\r\n]*""{fieldSeparator}[^|]+(?:\s*)";

var rx = new Regex(strRx);
var data = "row1 col1|\"row1 \\\"col2a\\\"\r\nrow1 \\\"col2b\\\"\"|row1 col3\nrow2 col1|\"row2 col2a\rrow2 col2b\"";

var m = rx.Match(data);

while (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Just replace `fieldSeparator` value with whatever field delimiter you want to use.

Above code snippet produce following output:

```
row1 col1
"row1 \"
col2a\"
row1 \"col2b\""
row1 col3
row2 col1
row2 col2b"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Saleem.  This does split the fields correctly, but does not give me the line before the fields.  Because each line represents a record, I need each line first, and then I can use your regex to obtain the fields.  I suppose I could determine how many fields a record has, and then iterate over all fields (as given by your regex) and populate the record by index.  But for now, I'll just continue going line by line.  Thanks!